# The method nextInt is undefined for the type secure random

Tags: java

Im trying to generate random number with this code, but constantly getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method nextInt(int) is undefined for the type SecureRandom

    at SecureRandom.main(SecureRandom.java:18)
```

Here's what I have tried

```
public class SecureRandom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
    for (int count = 1; count <=20; count++) {

        int face = 1+randomNumbers.nextInt(6);
        System.out.printf( " %d" , face);

        if (count %5 ==0) {
        System.out.println();
        }

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: `at SecureRandom.main` is your clue. You have two classes with exactly the same name, how do you think Java will handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is resolving `SecureRandom` against the class you defined. You should change the class name to avoid the conflict with `java.security.SecureRandom`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have called your own class `SecureRandom`, the compiler is using that class in your main method while you wanted to use `java.security.SecureRandom`.
You can force the compiler to use the latter by using canonical name of the class in your code:

```
public class SecureRandom {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.security.SecureRandom randomNumbers = new java.security.SecureRandom();
      for (int count = 1; count <=20; count++) {
         int face = 1+randomNumbers.nextInt(6);
         System.out.printf( " %d" , face);
         if (count %5 ==0) {
            System.out.println();
         }
      }
   }

}
```